# Elastic Search Implementation as a Microservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, microservices

I want to implement Elastic Search as a microservice. We would have 2 apps, where the main app will be connected to Relational Db and the other app will have all the logic for the Elastic search. Now, in the main app, any change would emit a unique event with the payload having all the relevant info around that change.

With the Elastic Search in place, the main app will send this event to the Elastic Search service to process. I am planning to have services for indexing each index table in elastic search. This service will process the event and make the addition/update/deletion based on the event in that index.

A single event can also be processed by multiple services if the index related to that service includes the data change related to that event.

I am just worried if this would be the right way to approach. I can see a single service(class) would grow huge with too many events being processed for indexing.

I would code this in ruby, and there is a gem called elasticsearch-model which is used by most people and is mentioned in every other blog. But I don't want to get restricted by that and also it would not be possible to use it in the kind of microservice setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used elasticsearch-model gem in my current web application you can override it's CRUD methods into your ruby code as used them as REST API Architecture

or

If you don't want to use this gem then you can also create REST api for your elasticsearch and implement your desired features.

Comment: My question is more inclined towards structuring code for indexing various things happening around the application. When we use the gem, it sits on top of the model and captures the changes and index to elastic search. I want to know if there is an alternative approach to not using gem for indexing. One that I am proposing in the question is using various services/classes, each to represent one index and handle events in there for what changes to make in the index based on the event). I am confused about scaling it.